# Da dove viene l'uso di chiamare delle celebrità con "nome + nazionale"?

Tags: phrase-origin

Si legge abbastanza spesso di personalità del mondo dello spettacolo o dello sport chiamate con il loro nome di battesimo seguito da "nazionale". Una su tutte: la Raffaella nazionale (["La Raffaella nazionale compie 75 anni"](https://www.msn.com/it-it/notizie/italia/la-raffaella-nazionale-compie-75-anni/vi-AAyO0jl), ["La più amata dagli italiani: Raffaella nazionale"](https://italoamericano.org/story/2013-7-3/Raffaella-Nazionale) eccetera). Troviamo anche la ["Federica nazionale"](https://www.repubblica.it/2009/07/sport/nuoto/filippi-ora-tocca-a-me/filippi-ora-tocca-a-me/filippi-ora-tocca-a-me.html) (ossia Federica Pellegrini), la ["Samantha nazionale"](https://attivissimo.blogspot.com/2015/03/parentopoli-allagenzia-spaziale.html?m=1) che altri non è che la cara Cristoforetti, la ["Michelle - Hunziker - nazionale"](https://www.bergamonews.it/2018/02/08/michelle-marica-bellissime-gusti-simili-amore-gl-abiti/275624/).

Dove ha origine quest'espressione?

Comment: Ammetto di non conoscere l'ultima, che forse è nota soprattutto in area napoletana. Come si chiama in realtà?

Comment: Ho dato per scontato che fosse il suo nome d'arte, ma non trovo il suo nome vero da nessuna parte... dunque forse nel suo caso è solo il cognome. Se ci fosse un neomelodica.stackexchange lo chiederei lì :D

Comment: Ok, sembra che Nazionale sia davvero il suo cognome. Cancello quella frase. (Ad ogni modo, "preclara" era ironico :D)

Comment: Michelle -Hunziker - internazionale in quanto ubiquitaria in TV :)